# Help me to visualise limit points of $S$.

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

Consider the ordered square $I^2,$ then the set $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with the dictionary order. Let the general element of $I^2$ be denoted by $x\times y,$ where $x,y\in[0,1].$ The closure of the subset $$S=\{x\times\frac{3}{4}:0<a<x<b<1\}$$ in $I^2$ is

$(A)S\bigcup ((a,b]\times \{0\})\bigcup ([a,b)\times \{1\})$

$(B)S\bigcup ([a,b)\times \{0\})\bigcup ((a,b]\times \{1\})$

$(C)S\bigcup ((a,b)\times \{0\})\bigcup ((a,b)\times \{1\})$

$(D)S\bigcup ((a,b]\times \{0\})$

**My attempt:-[image]

Case 1:-

$a\times b \notin S$. There is an open set containing $a \times b$ which does not intersect $S$(shown in the figure).

Case 2:-

$a\times b \in S$. There is an open set containing $a \times b$ which does not intersect $S\setminus \{a\times b\}$

So, none of the points is a limit point in $I^2$. But Options are different. Can you help me to visualize?

Comment: In your work, you have used $(a,b)$ as the coordinates of an arbitrary point. But if you go back and look at the definition of $S$, you see that $a, b$ are used in defining it. That is, they have set values. You need to use a different pair of letters to represent your arbitrary point, and then consider the impact of the fact that $S = (a,b) \times \left\{\frac 34\right\}$ for some $a,b$ with $0 < a < b < 1$. The other thing you need to consider is what happens when $s = 0$ or $s = 1$. Your diagram does not hold for that $(r,s)$. Also, case 2 is immaterial. $S$ is always in its closure.

Comment: Please upvote/accept an answer, to be able to close a new question as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case you drew, namely: $S= (0,1) \times \{\frac34\}$:

Of course points of $S$ are always in the closure of $S$, but the points with second coordinates $0$ and $1$ require more thought..

Consider what a (basic) neighbourhood of $a \times 0$ where $a >0$ looks like:
it's an open interval $I$ with left endpoint $c \times d \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ and right end point $e \times f$. (only $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ have half-open half-closed basic neighbourhoods, as they are the minimum and maximum in the order).

The only way (in the lexicographic order) that $c \times d < (a \times 0)$ can hold, is when $c < a$ ($c=a$ is ruled out, as we cannot go below $0$ in the second coordinate). But then if we pick $c'$ with $c < c' < a$ (wich we can) then $c'\times \frac34$ lies above $c \times d$ and below $a \times 0$ and so lies in $I$. So $S$ intersects all basic open neighbourhoods of $a \times 0$, $a \times 0$ is a limit point of $S$.

If the second coordiante of a point $x \times y$ lies in $(0,1)$ and the point lies outside $S$, we *can* pick a small open interval around it that misses $S$.

For points of the form $a \times 1$ we can hold a simialr reasoning that all their basic open intervals also intersects $S$. The only points it fails are the said min and max. We do add $0 \times 1$ and $1 \times 0$ as limit points.

The general case that's asked for then has answer $A$, I think.

Comment: when I drew the line $a \times 0$ It lies as the portion of $x$-axis.

Comment: which is entirely disjoint from $(0<a,b<1)\times \{\frac{3}{4}\}$

Comment: $a \times 0$ is meant as what?

Comment: sorry! Henno, I was busy with my UG project.  $0<a<1,a\times 0$. a line segment in x axis.

Comment: I have a doubt in your second paragraph. How $c' \times \frac{3}{4}$ lies in  $S$. $c'<a$. So,  $c' \times \frac{3}{4}<a\times \frac{3}{4}$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mathgeek If $S$ is $(a,b) \times \frac34$ so with boundaries $a$ and $b$ on the $x$-axis, then my argument will show that $(x,0)$ lies in $S'$ for all $x \in (a,b]$. At first I wrote my answer for the drawn case of $a=0,b=1$ and later tried to generalise. Also, $(x,1) \in S'$ for $x \in [a,b)$ as well.

Comment: No you are wrong. $a \times 0$ is not a limit point of $S.$ Because the point $c' \times \frac 3 4$ you obtain is not in $S.$

Comment: @mathmaniac. I have shown that $0 \times 0$ is not a limit point of $S$ as defined at the beginning, while points of the form $a\times 0$ with $a>0$ is. So the lower left boundary point at level $0$ is not a limit point. Hence the final answer of A.

Comment: But what you are claiming that $a \times 0$ is a limit point of $S$ is not at all a limit point of $S.$ Take any $0 \leq p < a, $ any $0 \leq q \leq 1$ and any $0 < r \leq 1$ and consider the basic open set $B = (p \times q, a \times r)$ in $I^2.$ Then clearly $B$ is an open neighbourhood of $a \times 0.$ But can it contain any point of $S$?

Comment: @mathmaniac. No that’s not what I claimed at all. A is the right answer. My $S$ is different from the OP’s $S$, beware!

Comment: Oh! I see now. I thought $S$ is the set what OP mentioned. Pardon me please.