# Closure of the set in dictionary order topology.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the ordered square $I_0^2$, the set $[0,1]\times [0,1]$  with the dictionary order topology. Let the general element of $I_0^2$ be denoted by $x\times y$, where $x, y\in [0,1]$. Then the closure of the subset $$S = \big\{x\times \frac{3}{4}: 0<a<x<b<1\big\}$$ in $I_0^2$ is

1. $S\cup \big((a, b]\times\{0\}\big) \cup \big([a, b)\times \{1\}\big)$
2. $S\cup \big((a, b]\times\{0\}\big) \cup \big((a, b]\times \{1\}\big)$
3. $S\cup \big((a, b)\times\{0\}\big) \cup \big((a, b)\times \{1\}\big)$
4. $S\cup \big((a, b]\times\{0\}\big)$

please explain it properly. I have no idea how to start with?

Comment: When you say dictionary order, do you mean $(x,y)>(z,w)$ if $x>z$ or $x=z$ and $y>w$?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Start with the observation that a basis for the topology's open sets is open vertical intervals.  Since the open sets are "thin," that means the closed sets are "fat."  Does that help?

Comment: See my answer for this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3120279/4280)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(p,0)$ be in $[0,1]^2$ in this order topology, where $0 < p$. A basic open neighbourhood of $(p,0)$ is an open interval with endpoints in $[0,1]^2$, say $\langle (l_1,l_2), (r_1,r_2)\rangle$. It follows by the definition of the lexicographic order that $l_1 < p$. A moment's thought reveals that we can in fact only need to consider basic open sets of the form $\langle (l_1,1), (p,r_2)\rangle$ for $(p,0)$ (with $0< l_1 < p, r_2 >0$), by shrinking such an open interval.

For a point $(q,1), q < 1$ we likewise only need to consider open basic sets of the form $\langle (q,l_1), (r_1,0)\rangle$ (with $l_1 > 0, q < r_1 < 1$).

It's then easy to see that a point $(p,0) \in \overline{S}$ iff $p \in (a,b]$ and $(q,1) \in \overline{S}$ iff $q \in [a,b)$.